# How to use variable in system() in c

Tags: c

Please help me with my code. I am using the system() function in c. Let's say I want to make a new directory using C code.

```
char name[];

printf("Enter the name of directory: ");
scanf("%s", &name);
```

Then using `system()`, I want to use the variable `name[]` 
instead of using or putting a fixed value like `system("mkdir ryan");` which makes a new directory `ryan`; what I want to happen is that, to create any name of directory and store it to variable `name[]` and implement that value instead of `ryan`. Your answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: `system` is not the right way to call `mkdir`. There's a perfectly good `mkdir` function to call. Using `system` leads to all sorts of security, robustness, and performance issues that should never have been introduced to begin with. Basically, forget you ever heard of `system`. It should **absolutely never** be used.

Answer (score 6):

You should be using something like:

```
char name[100];
printf("Enter the name of the directory: ");
if (scanf("%99s", name) == 1)  // Not &name
{
    char command[120];
    sprintf("%s %s", "mkdir", name);
    if (system(command) != 0)
        ...oops...
}
```

Comment: Or use `snprintf` to make sure you can't overflow your buffer, regardless of how big you think is "big enough".

Comment: Since I limited the input to less than 100 characters, and `strlen("mkdir ")` is less than 20, this is safe as it stands.  In other circumstances, then `snprintf()` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

First off (and this probably doesn't matter if your code is just an example), don't ever use an unbounded `%s` `scanf` - that opens you up to buffer overflows.

If you have a string like:

```
char name[] = "paxdiablo";
```

you can just use that to construct your own string for execution.

```
char cmd[1000];
strcpy (cmd, "mkdir ");
strcat (cmd, name);
system (cmd);
```

And make sure you *know* (or check with `strlen`, or dynamically allocate the buffer so it's big enough) the size of `name` so that you don't end up with a buffer overflow there as well.

An example of the dynamic allocation one:

```
void tryMkdir (char *dir) {
    static char prefix[] = "mkdir ";
    // Use sizeof to allow for null char at end.
    char *cmd = malloc (sizeof (prefix) + strlen (dir));
    if (cmd != NULL) {
        strcpy (cmd, prefix);
        strcat (cmd, dir);
        system (cmd);
        free (cmd);
    }
}
```

(although you'd probably want some error checking in there in case the `mkdir` or `malloc` failed).

Comment: Nothing. There's many ways to do the job. For simple string concatenation, I prefer `strcat` rather than the full power of `snprintf` (there is no need for length checking here since we ensure the buffer is big enough). If I was constructing a string made up of more than two things or wasn't certain of the length, I'd probably switch but I don't find it necessary in this case.

Comment: It all sounds over complicated with the malloc, multiple calls etc - where one snprintf would do with an array on the stack of MAX_PATH size (not 100% sure on portability of that macro) And really the OP should be using a system call to create the directory - because its as limited as using a system call but without some weird side affect of executing an unsupported command against the OS

Comment: @Adrian, there's no max_path/path_max in C99 or C11. There's a filename_max but that can simply be the _recommended_ size rather than the maximium. And you're probably right about using platform-specific calls rather than `system` but the question was specifically about `system` with variables.

Comment: Agree - couldn't find it either - assumed then it was a POSIX extension thing although I believe its available in VS as well.

Comment: @paxdiablo, thanks alot. it really helped me. this is the answer of my problem:)

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of how it could be implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    char *dirname = NULL;
    char *cmdline = NULL;
    size_t len;
    size_t dirlen = 0;
    int rv = 0;

    printf("Enter directory: ");
    if ( (len = getline(&dirname, &dirlen, stdin)) < 0) {
        perror("getline");
        exit(-1);
    }

    dirname[len-1] = 0;
    cmdline = malloc(len+8);
    snprintf(cmdline, dirlen+8, "mkdir %s", dirname);
    rv = system(cmdline);
    free(cmdline);
    free(dirname);
    rv = WEXITSTATUS(rv);
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to free `dirname` too.  It might also be worth noting that [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) is in POSIX 2008 and, while available on Linux and *BSD (including MacOS X), it is not available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build up a string w/ your full command to send to system() in it, which means allocating space for it (which you didn't do for name in your original code, so that your call to scanf would likely fail).  For something like your mkdir example, you could create a string that starts with mkdir & has enough room after that for your directory name, and when you call scanf, point it to the location within that string you want the name to go; saves you having to do a strcat or somesuch afterward, and if this is the only thing you need the directory name for, why store it twice?

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
char command[80];
strcpy(command, "mkdir ");
strcat(command, name);
system(command);
```

Comment: you CANNOT use strcat with a const char * as the first parameter.

Comment: Why make it so complicated use snprintf

Comment: @AdrianCornish Sorry I never heard of that function before, I've mostly used C++ so far, and string concatenation was the first thing that sprung to mind

Comment: @ryannuada no problem, although my answer wasn't that helpful :P

Comment: If you're mostly using C++, `strcpy`/`strcat` should be the _last_ thing on your mind!